# mysql Like not work on strings which have alphanumeric correcters

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which has data in `column 1`, and data is `S01E01`. 
When I run:

```
select * from tableName where "column 1" like "S%"
```

it works properly, but when I run:

```
select * from tablename where "column 1" like "S0%"
```

it doesn't work (returns empty set).

I think it occurs when I insert a number in double quotes.

what is problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Then there's no record with 'S0%'

Comment: Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ", use ` on the field_name.

```
select * from tablename where `column 1` like "S0%"
```

Comment: Also if possible please change the field name into column_1 (remove the space). For example if you fetch the result data as array of objects, then the column name will be a key in the object.